# I need a php (pdo) code to view database full table with column names

Tags: php

I need a php (pdo) code to view database whatever table with it's column names and values in a html table format ..
I managed to do every thing except viewing the column names dinamically..

Here is a part of my code :

```
try {
     $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
     $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
     $stmt = $conn->prepare("$sql");
     $stmt->execute();
     $x=1;
     // set the resulting array to associative
     $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     echo "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Website</th><th>Comment</th><th>Gender</th></tr>";


     foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {

     echo $v;
     }
```

as you see i'm viewing the column names manually using normal echo statement.
any help appricated , thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can make additional SQL call to get columns from table: `SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name;`

Comment: I will Try it and get u back later , thanks my friend :)

Comment: but what if we don't know the table name that the user will use ?!
i have a text field where the user type his own query and click the excute button

Comment: You have `$sql` -- there is in any case presented name of table:)

Comment: i.e. just something like this: `$tbl_name=preg_match('/FROM\s+([^\s]+)/si',$sql,$m);` in `$m` you will find name of table

Comment: but $sql=$_POST["query"]; (any query is allowed , and the data base has more than one table)

Comment: Yes I understand it now

Comment: I Got an error
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\selection.php on line 54
Error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'form.array' doesn't exist

line 54 >> $sql2="SHOW COLUMNS FROM $m;";

Comment: `$m` it is array -- look into and you will see table name in `$m[1]` or `$m[2]` etc

Comment: yes i got that
the table name is stored in $m[1]..
but still can't get it work

Comment: $tbl_name=preg_match('/FROM\s+([^\s]+)/si',$sql,$m);
     $sql2="SHOW COLUMNS FROM $m[1];";
     $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("$sql2");
     $stmt2->execute();
     // set the resulting array to associative
     $result = $stmt2->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



     foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt2->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {

     echo $v;
     }

Comment: i got some other problems but finally worked !!
thank you

Answer (score 2):

With PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, the column names are the keys of the array elements, so $k.

First time you iterate over the result set, grab the keys. Or just do

```
$results=$stmt->fetchAll();
echo "<tr>";
foreach(array_keys($results[0]) as $column_name) echo "<th>$column_name</th>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Then continue with your loop over the fetchall (now stored in $results).

Alternately you could take your existing loop and add something that checks if it's the first iteration of the loop and prints the headers then